# Open active contours

Tags: matlab

Does anyone know how to make an open active contour. I'm familiar with closed contours and I have several Matlab programs describing them. I've tried to change the matrix A
but that was not enough, so does anyone have a Matlab program or any other good advise showing how to make a non-closed active contour?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I will try to be more specific: I have modified the coefficient matrix A in order to handle open active contouraccording to http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/217: The matrix they propose is as follows